# cordova dialog plugin stacking alerts

Tags: cordova

I'm using the `cordova-plugin-dialogs` to display alerts in an ionic application. I'd like to see if there is already an alert on display and dismiss that one before showing another alert. Is this possible ?

Comment: no, it's not possible. If your problem is that you can't show a new one when there is another one present it's been fixed on the github version of the plugin

Comment: @jcesarmobile - that's all i needed to know. Can you answer this so that I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: I answered long time ago can you mark it? I've updated as the fix was published on NPM too

Answer (score 1):

[There was a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562791/cordova-dialog-plugin-stacking-alerts) on the dialogs plugin that doesn't allow to stack more than one dialog.

It's been fixed [on the github repository](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs) and the changes have been released on the latest version (1.2) and published on NPM